# How to get the finger-print of a computer via browser?

Tags: node.js, browser, unique

How can i uniquely identify a computer via a browser? My web server is NodeJS. Although i give login feature to the users, i need to map the user's browser to their computers. (A user should not be able to login into other computers)

What do you think? Is there a way to achieve this?

Note:
 1) I do not require browser finger-print. I need computer finger-print. 
 2) I assign the computer and login credentials for the first time to the users.

Comment: Are your users accessing the service over the public internet? Or on an internal intranet?

Comment: It is an intranet service.

Comment: Are the computers locked down and controlled by something like group policy? Or do users have admin rights?

Comment: I'm sorry I made a typo.. It's **Internet** service actually.

Comment: Then it's not really possible to do in a secure way

Comment: If your app is deployed on the same computer, you can use Node's `process.env.ComputerName` to get the Computer Name. Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62408633