# How to prevent an offline Angular+Express based application from getting stolen?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, angular, sqlite, express

Last year, I developed a simple Angular-Express-SQLite based application for a local Warehouse(Logistics Hub) which was used to keep track of daily incoming and outgoing trucks with information like their weight, origin, etc. and I deployed the app on an offline desktop.
Everything went well until I came to know that the computer operator of the Warehouse resold the app to other Warehouses for a decent amount.

Now, the first Warehouse owner has contacted me again with some changes in the app with some crucial inputs as per the new guidelines from the government, I'm looking for some solution to prevent the app from getting stolen again.

1. I'm looking for a solution that is as light in size as possible because of the type of desktops the app runs on are way too cheap(with lowest possible configuration), hence the choice of SQLite instead of some other Database providers.
2. The app should be deployed in such a manner that it can't be copy-pasted from one machine to other. It could be achieved by simple, not so secure methods too as the operators aren't that tech-savvy and only know the bare minimum knowledge about Computers, like copy-paste.

Comment: Technical solutions to this problem will be a.) fragile, b.) cumbersome and c.) never perfect. You really should go a legal route here .... copyright is on your side. Assuming you licensed the software to him with an actual contract and not just by word-of-mouth. That being said, if you only want to prevent low-skill attacks, then contacting a central server on each startup to communicate some stats and check if the user is authentic could be sufficient.

Comment: or try an usb dongle

Comment: I couldn't go the legal route as it was a handshake deal. 
The desktop is not connected to the Internet, it's an offline app.

Answer (score 1):

So I came across a low-level workaround since I'll be the one who'd set up the application on the client machine.

While initialising the application, an encrypted entry in the database could be set up with the name of the computer by reading the environment variable using express/node.

```
process.env.COMPUTERNAME
```

Or using some other system variable unique to that particular Computer and then comparing the stored value and current value on every login.

Answer (score 0):

As Joachim already said in his comment, if the App has internet access, you can check for a license-key or something similar on a server.

Perhaps something like PKG can help, which compiles your sources into a single executable file. [PKG on npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg)

Comment: App works in an offline environment.
Would PKG work for Angular apps?

Comment: I guess so. I am coming from react, but angular has nodejs as a base too, doesn't it?